"let me explain to you some details" versus "let me explain some details to you"
I read the first one sentence in a book.
1

"let me explain to you some details "

But I thought it should be
2

"let me explain some details  to you"

Are both grammatically correct?
According to Oxford dictionary
it seems that explain  (something) to someone is correct.
which is like the second one.
Could someone help me understand that?

I'm sure this is a duplicate, but can't find it. "to you" goes before the direct object if the direct object is a long phrase ("let me explain to you the reason why I am unable to do that") but after if the direct object is a short phrase ("let me explain the facts to you").

Related but not really answered as such: Position of direct object and prepositional phrase

This question is similar to: "He put on the shelf a box" -- can this be considered correct?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. // shoover's answer explains this well; the answers at the claimed duplicate there don't. Stuart summarises clearly above.

I hear such ordering as a leak from German, Yiddish, and other structures.
